# Correctly Resume Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have Activity sequence like this:

`A` => `B` => `C` => `D` => `E`

On ButtonClick in `E` activity, I'm Resuming `C`. And after I click `back` button in `C`, it goes back to `E` not `B`.

I want to have `C` => `B` => `A` sequence on `back` button clicks after resuming `C` activity.

how am I supposed to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start activity `C` by providing [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) in the intent. The `C` activity will be started after closing all activities that are on top `C`.

```
Intent ci = new Intent(this,C.class);
ci.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(ci);
```

Flags used when starting `C`:

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
`A` - `B` - `C` - `D` - `E` **to** `A` - `B` - `C`.

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT :](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
`A` - `B` - `C` - `D` - `E` **to** `A` - `B` - `D` - `E` - `C`.

Comment: I was using `ReorderToFront`. I'll try others and reply back.

Comment: OK, I think `ClearTop` is what I need. but I'm losing data when I use it. 

what is the best way to store data somewhere `onPause` and retrieve it `onResume`?

Comment: Used `ClearTop` and added `LaunchMode` to `SingleTop` and now everything works great. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All are activities so just do the following on back button click -

From C -

```
 backButtonC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
            //extras
            C.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

From B -

```
 backButtonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
            //extras
            B.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The onBackPressed() method defines the action that takes place when the back button is pressed. So, basically if you finish the activity inside onBackPressed(), the activity is removed from the Activity stack. You may explicitly call Activity B from Activity C from onBackPressed().

```
public void onBackPressed() {

super.onBackPressed();
Intent i=new Intent(this,B.class)
startActivity(i);

}
```

Similarly, start A from B and finish at A.